# logj4 with Spring MVC 3.2.8 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I have an application based in the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework using logj4. Here my `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, logfile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}] %5p [%t] %x (%C:%L) - %m%n

org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy


log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logs/noentenimnicinc.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=1512KB
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.logfile.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=ecat_admin.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz

# Keep three backup files.
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
# Pattern to output: date priority [category] - message
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}] %5p [%t] %x (%C:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=CONSOLE
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}] %5p [%t] %x (%C:%L) - %m%n
```

and my controller:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class NoEnTenimNiCinc {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger   (NoEnTenimNiCinc.class);

    private void fer () {

        LOGGER.info("***************************************************************");
        LOGGER.info("   SUBMITTING THE APPLICATION ");
        LOGGER.info("***************************************************************");

        System.out.println  ("System.out***************************************************************");
        System.out.println  ("System.out    SUBMITTING THE APPLICATION ");
        System.out.println  ("System.out***************************************************************");
    }       
}
```

As far as I understand I should see in the eclipse console all the messages but I only see the ones generated by `System.out.println`

Comment: I think that CONSOLE is not a valid value for Threshold in `log4j.appender.console.Threshold=CONSOLE`

Comment: I removed this value with the same result :-(

Comment: Hope you got the clue by now. I would recommend you to use slf4j for your logging and in background use logback instead of log4j if you are newly implementing logging in your app. Also have a look at java servlet filter API and spring AOP. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ConsoleAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html) has threshold field inherited from class org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton. Threshold is a [`Prority`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Priority.html) Object and its possible values are:

- DEBUG
- ERROR
- FATAL
- INFO
- WARN
- ...

`Console` is not a possible value for it.

Comment: indeed, but this change unfortunately solved my problem :-(